# Data from two Android activities shown on one layout?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am very new to Android developing, so hopefully this is an easy one to answer. I have done lots of searching but cannot find an answer - possibly I am going about it the wrong way.

I have two class files, one is to get the battery level info (class A below) and the other uses TelephonyManager to get the device IMEI and display that (class B below).

I cannot work out how you can get the values of these two classes to appear on the same layout.

This is class A:

```
package com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class AboutScreen extends ListActivity {  
/** Called when the activity is first created. */  

private String[] strText = new String[] {"Battery Level", "Voltage", "Status"};  
  private int voltage = 0;  
  private boolean trun = true;  
  private Handler myHandler = new Handler();  
  private Runnable myRun = new Runnable() {  
       public void run() {  
            updateNow();  
       }  
  };  
  // using Thread to keep the process running  
  private Thread myThread = new Thread() {  
       public void run () {  
            do {  
              batteryLevelUpdate();  
              myHandler.post(myRun);  
              try {  
                      Thread.sleep(1000);  
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                      e.printStackTrace();  
                 }                   
            } while (trun);  
       }  
  };  
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "email", 2000).show();  
 startMonitor();  
}  
@Override  
public void onDestroy() {  
    trun = false;  
    super.onDestroy();  
}  

private void startMonitor() {  
    myThread.start();  
}  
private void updateNow() {  
    ListView thisListView = getListView();  
    thisListView.setEnabled(false);  
    ArrayAdapter<String> myList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.about_screen, strText);  
    thisListView.setAdapter(myList);  
}  
private void batteryLevelUpdate() {  
 BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {  
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        context.unregisterReceiver(this);  
     int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);  
     int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);  
     int level = -1;  
     if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {  
       level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;  
     }  
     voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);  
     int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);  
     int onplug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);  
     boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;  
     boolean onUSB = onplug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;  
     boolean onAC = onplug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;  
     String strStatus = "Charging on ";  
     if (isCharging && onUSB)  
          strStatus += "USB";  
     else if (isCharging && onAC)  
          strStatus += "AC Power";  
     else  
          strStatus = "Battery Discharging";          



     strText[0] = "Battery Level: " + Integer.toString(level) + "%";  
     strText[1] = "Voltage: " + Integer.toString(voltage) + "mV";  
     strText[2] = strStatus;  
     //strText[3] = "test";
   }  
 };  
 IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);  
 registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);  
}  
}
```

This is class B:

```
package com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidTelephonyManager extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.phone);
    TextView textDeviceID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.deviceid);

    //retrieve a reference to an instance of TelephonyManager
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    textDeviceID.setText(getDeviceID(telephonyManager));

}

String getDeviceID(TelephonyManager phonyManager){

 String id = phonyManager.getDeviceId();
 if (id == null){
  id = "not available";
 }

 int phoneType = phonyManager.getPhoneType();
 switch(phoneType){
 case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE:
  return "NONE: " + id;

 case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM:
  return "GSM: IMEI=" + id;

 case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA:
  return "CDMA: MEID/ESN=" + id;

 /*
  *  for API Level 11 or above
  *  case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_SIP:
  *   return "SIP";
  */

 default:
  return "UNKNOWN: ID=" + id;
 }

}
}
```

This is the layout file which displays the battery level info just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <TextView  
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
     android:padding="10dp"  
             android:textSize="12sp"   
             android:clickable="false" />
```

However I have no idea how you can get the IMEI info from the class B to show as well. Ideally it would be another list row underneath the battery level items. Any advice on how you can combine different activities into one layout would be really useful.

Apologies if my explanation isn't great, but my java understanding is novice at the moment.

Many thanks

Comment: Do both the things in a single activity only...

Answer (score 0):

Use static method, for example

```
static String getDeviceID(TelephonyManager phonyManager)
```

then call the methods with class name,

classB.getDeviceID(phonyManager);

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have got some basic concept wrong here. `Activity` is only for UI. Its not required that you need one `Activity` for one particular functionality. So you can have both the functionalities in one single activity, and update its layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can write these values into Sharedpreferences....

`getSharedPreferences("sp", MODE_PRIVATE).
                    edit().
                    putString("login", ed_login.getText().toString()).
                    commit();`

So then you can get it anywhere by ...

```
getSharedPreferences("sp", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("login", "");
```